# ISO C++ errors when compiling C code

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to compile a .C file, which includes a corresponding .h like this one

```
typedef struct myType
{
    char* myString = "NOT SET";
    int   myInt    = -1;
}
```

Running "gcc -c myFile.c" raises the following errors:

```
Error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of member 'myString'
Error: making 'myString' static
Error: invalid in-class initialization of static data member of non-integral type ‘char*’
Error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of member 'myInt'
Error: making 'myInt' static
Error: invalid in-class initialization of static data member of non-integral type ‘int’
```

So my question is two-fold: First, why can't I initialize values for the struct in my header? And second, why am I getting ISO C++ errors when I'm compiling C code?

Comment: C or C++? THe include you show argues for C++ btw.

Comment: Please create a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) / [alternative](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Is it legal to initialize stuff in `struct` like this? I thought that it's legal only since C++11...

Comment: do not use `typedef struct` idiom it is evil

Answer (score 2):

`gcc` automatically goes into C++ mode when the file extension is `.C` (capital letter 'C'). Ensure your C source files have the extension `.c` (lower case letter 'c').